# Что значит $event.ReplacementStrings[0] -notlike '*$' в powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

Есть скрипт который находит все случаи логина пользователей в домене ActiveDirectory c 12:00 до 00:00 часов за указанные последние несколько дней.

```
$alluserhistory = @()
[int] $days = Read-Host "Days count"
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays($days)
$DCs = Get-ADDomainController -Filter *
foreach ($DC in $DCs){
$logonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -InstanceID 4624 -after "12:00" -before "00:00" -ComputerName $dc.HostName
foreach ($event in $logonevents){
if ($event.ReplacementStrings[0] -notlike '*$') {
$userhistory = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
UserName = $event.ReplacementStrings[0]
IPAddress = $event.ReplacementStrings[9]
Date = $event.TimeGenerated
DC = $dc.Name
}
$alluserhistory += $userhistory
}
}
}
$alluserhistory
```

Я не понимаю, что именно делает проверка
`$event.ReplacementStrings[0] -notlike '*$'`
Почему строка замены (что бы это не было) не должна быть равна '*$'?

Comment: Выражение -notlike в PowerShell если перевести - не похоже на.

В скрипте проверка $event.ReplacementStrings[0] -notlike '*$' означает, что скрипт будет фильтровать результаты, и если поле ReplacementStrings[0] (имя пользователя) не заканчивается на символ $, то эти результаты будут добавлены в массив $alluserhistory. Это может использоваться для исключения служебных учетных записей, которые часто заканчиваются на $.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ дан в комментарии:

Выражение "notlike" в *PowerShell*, если перевести - "не похоже на".

В скрипте проверка `$event.ReplacementStrings[0] -notlike '*$'` означает, что скрипт будет фильтровать результаты, и если поле `ReplacementStrings[0]` (имя пользователя) не заканчивается на символ `$`, то эти результаты будут добавлены в массив `$alluserhistory`.

Это может использоваться для исключения служебных учетных записей, которые часто заканчиваются на `$`. – [Aleksandr Fetisov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/492732/aleksandr-fetisov)